# Building project targeting msbuild 4 from an msbuild 2 script using TeamCity

Tags: .net, msbuild, teamcity

I have a msbuild script that builds multiple projects using TeamCity. It builds a few C++ builder 2010 projects, and some C# projects. It also creates an installer for them and packages it all. Now I have a new project that I want to add, but the problem is that it's build using .Net Framework 4, while the other older ones, along with the build scripts themselves, target .Net Framework 2.

In the settings in TeamCity it's selected to build using msbuild 2 and changing it to 4 (hoping it was backwards compatible) just causes massive amounts of errors.

I was wondering if there is a good way to make a specific projects build using msbuild 4 instead, without resorting to making new buildsteps in TeamCity.

I tried invoking msbuild 4 from msbuild 2 using the exec comand and it worked fine. But perhaps there is some "nicer" way of doing it.

Example of what "worked"

```
<Exec Command="C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\MSBuild /t:FooBar /p:Configuration=Debug ..\FooBar\FooBar.sln"/>
```

**Update:** I managed to get all the old stuff compiling using msbuild and .Net Framework 4. So this isn't really an issue anymore.

Comment: Just a question why don't separate builds in separate configurations?

Comment: Because I want the build to be easy to run from point A to point B from a cmd if a user wants to do that without having to remember to run specific steps first.

Comment: You could have separate cmd files an one big to call small one for each project

Comment: True, but that would kinda be like calling a new instance of msbuild of a specific version using the exec command. Anyway, the solution of actually making the older stuff compile using newer version of msbuild seemed like the correct thing to do ;)

Comment: This doesn't work for BlackBerry. If you build app with newer tool it won't run on older devices. But I hope in desktop world it's much better. All the best!

Comment: Yes, you can actually build using msbuild 4 but state that you target a specific version of .Net Framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it the "correct" way. Making sure all the old stuff could be built using the newer msbuild and target the .Net Framework they were intended for. The approach of using *exec* also worked but always felt like a hack.